# SpriteKit - Scale node to X from right to left

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, sprite-kit

I have a SKNode that is a load bar. This bar is supposed to shrink from right to left. For doing this I use the following code:

```
let loadBarNode = self.childNodeWithName("loadBar")

    if loadBarNode != nil{

       let countdown = SKAction.scaleXTo(0, duration: 3)
        loadBarNode?.runAction(countdown)

    }
```

When I run this code, this happens:

[image: What happens when code runs.]

I would like to know how to shrink the shape from right to left, like this:

[image: It's supposed to look like this.]

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe a simpler solution is to change the anchor of your node.

```
loadBarNode.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.5)
```

Scaling is based on the anchorPoint of your node and this would cause it to expand to the right.

Answer (score 3):

Make an SKAction sequence that has your countdown action, plus an SKAction which moves your X.

> class func moveToX(_ x: CGFloat,
>             duration sec: NSTimeInterval) -> SKAction

So as your load bar shrinks, you want to offset your X by half the shrunk distance.

Comment: @sangony Actually though, after thinking this through again...They need to run simultaneously. So would a sequence work? But still, thanks for the compliment good sir!

Comment: Use a block to do both simultaneously.

Comment: @sangony could you please explain yourself a little better?

Comment: @OmarDlhz - You can scale your node and move it as Roecrew suggested but as he said, it will have to be simultaneously. Here is an example on how to use blocks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29354494/how-should-i-resize-label-nodes-in-spritekit/29354830#29354830

Answer (score 0):

I agree with changing the anchor point but more information for people who are new with this anchor point. It's not same with node's position and you can use storyboard to change anchor point of node rather than doing it programmatically. This is how :

[image]

Hopefully it can give more information. Thank you.